# jQuery div dialog open in the same page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I used jQuery div dialog to show new user page as show in picture

[image: http://www.4shared.com/photo/VGtCVSkv/newuser.html]

But when I press save button the new userpage is opening in the same page as show in the picture

[image: http://www.4shared.com/photo/T_wkDnMG/savenew.html]

Markup:

```
<ul class="menu" style="margin-left:10px; background-color:transparent; width:100%;">
    <li>
        <input type="button" ID="btnNew" value="Add New" style="background-color:transparent; border:0;" runat="server" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Code-Behind:

```
btnNew.Attributes.Add("onClick", "ShowEntityEditor('NewUser.aspx','userID',0,'New User',300,650);")
```

JavaScript: (placed in the master page)

```
function ShowEntityEditor(url, pname, entityID, txttitle, h, w) {
    var _editWindowDiv;
    _editWindowDiv = $("#_editWindowDiv").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: h,
        width: w,
        position: 'center',
        title: txttitle
    });
    _editWindowDiv.empty();
    _editWindowDiv.load(url + "?" + pname + "=" + entityID, function () {
        $("#cancelButtoon").click(function () {
            _editWindowDiv.dialog("close");
            return false;
        });
    });
    _editWindowDiv.dialog("open");
}
```

Comment: You need to provide example code. What code are you using.

Comment: i used this code 
<ul class="menu" style="margin-left:10px; background-color:transparent;  width:100%;">
        <li ><input type="button"  ID="btnNew"  value="Add New" style="background-color:transparent; border:0;" runat="server" /></li></ul>
then in the asp.net code bihind
btnNew.Attributes.Add("onClick", "ShowEntityEditor('NewUser.aspx','userID',0,'New User',300,650);")
the ShowEntityEditor placed in the master page

Comment: function ShowEntityEditor(url,pname,entityID,txttitle,h,w) {
            var _editWindowDiv;
            _editWindowDiv = $("#_editWindowDiv").dialog({ autoOpen: false, height: h, width: w, position: 'center', title: txttitle });
            _editWindowDiv.empty();
            _editWindowDiv.load(url+"?"+pname+"=" + entityID, function () { $("#cancelButtoon").click(function () { _editWindowDiv.dialog("close"); return false; }); });
            _editWindowDiv.dialog("open");

        }

Comment: Probably you should edit your question and place the code there?

Comment: The 'Save' button is probably doing a standard form post which changes the entire page.  You probably want to handle the form submission using jQuery/AJAX and then close the dialog box.

Comment: Are you including the jQueryUI CSS file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the newUser.aspx page use the following code to prevent the page form being submitted. submit newUser.aspx will close the dialog and redirect to the page.

```
   <script>
   $("#userForm").submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
     });
   </script>
```